App is crashing when using flutter_foreground_task
I am using flutter_foreground_task to get the to run a location foreground service.
As suggested, I have added the permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION"/>
When the user permissions are provided as "Allow all the time" for location, the foreground service is working as expected. But when "Allow while using the app" is selected, I am getting the following error
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type location targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission
I am not sure why this is happening. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
